# MapView delegate issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on MapView. The mapView delegate method `didSelectAnnotationView` get called when I tap on Pin but when I tap on Pin again this method does not get called until I don't click on map.

I want whenever I click on location Pin the method `didSelectAnnotationView` get called.
Please help

This is `didSelectAnnotationView` method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView{
    id<MKAnnotation> annotation = aView.annotation;
    if (!annotation || ![aView isSelected])
        return;

    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"My Location"])
        return;

    NSLog(@"Annotation Title: %@",[annotation title]);

    if(self.calloutAnnotation != nil)
    {        
        [pMapView removeAnnotation:self.calloutAnnotation];
        self.calloutAnnotation = nil;
        return;
    }

    if ( NO == [annotation isKindOfClass:[MultiRowCalloutCell class]])
    {
        NSObject <MultiRowAnnotationProtocol> *pinAnnotation = (NSObject <MultiRowAnnotationProtocol> *)annotation;
        if (!self.calloutAnnotation)
        {
            self.calloutAnnotation = [[MultiRowAnnotation alloc] init];
            [self.calloutAnnotation copyAttributesFromAnnotation:pinAnnotation];
            [mapView addAnnotation:self.calloutAnnotation];
        }

        self.selectedAnnotationView = aView;
        return;
    }

    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:annotation.coordinate animated:YES];
    self.selectedAnnotationView = aView;
}
```

Comment: Share the didSelectAnnotationView method you've written?

Comment: @GenieWanted: shared

Comment: it is a default nature of didSelectAnnotationView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having same problem but I solved it. Call didDeselectAnnotationView method and remove it from the superview.Like this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
for (UIView *subview in view.subviews ){
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

It worked for me,hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma mark MapView Delegate Methods

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView
   {
        indexPathTag=aView.tag;
        [mapView deselectAnnotation:aView.annotation animated:YES];

    }
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView
    {
    }
```

I have faced the same problem.This worked for me :)
Hope this will work for u too.
Thanks